# Failing to receive data when making call to an API with retrofit2

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

I'm making a simple app that has to make a call to an API that returns an object with some attributes and is shown in a RecyclerView.

The call is being made to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=0&_limit=5

The app doesn't crash, the recyclerview is being generated but it is empty. I used the debugger and saw that the list in the adapter of the recyclerview is empty (the size is 0).

I believe the issue is with the structure of the java objects I made but I can't confirm it for sure and I can't seem to modify my object structure to match that of the returned object. I'm not seeing an object with other objects inside of like with other apis I've worked on (when I check the above link with a json online reader).

I usually make my object and another object container (which has a list of the first object). My suspicion is that the issue is there, please help me find the problem.
Below the main activity, object, object container, adapter, retrofit object, object dao and object controller.

Activity:

```
public class PhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterPhotoRecyclerView.SelectedPhotoListener {

    private AdapterPhotoRecyclerView adapterPhotoRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.photo_activity_progress_bar);

        makeCall("photos?_start=0&_limit=5");

        adapterPhotoRecyclerView = new AdapterPhotoRecyclerView(this);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.photo_activity_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPhotoRecyclerView);


    }

    public void makeCall(String fixedUrl) {
        MyPhotoController myPhotoController = new MyPhotoController();
        myPhotoController.getPhotos(fixedUrl, new ResultListener<MyPhotoContainer>() {
            @Override
            public void finish(MyPhotoContainer result) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                adapterPhotoRecyclerView.setMyPhotoList(result.getmPhotoList());
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void selectePhoto(Integer position, List<MyPhoto> myPhotoList) {
        MyPhoto clickedPhoto = myPhotoList.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, clickedPhoto.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Adapter of the RecyclerView

```
public class AdapterPhotoRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPhotoRecyclerView.PhotoViewHolder> {
    private List<MyPhoto> myPhotoList;
    private SelectedPhotoListener selectedPhotoListener;

    public AdapterPhotoRecyclerView(SelectedPhotoListener selectedPhotoListener) {
        myPhotoList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.selectedPhotoListener = selectedPhotoListener;
    }

    public void setMyPhotoList(List<MyPhoto> myPhotoList) {
        this.myPhotoList = myPhotoList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public List<MyPhoto> getMyPhotoList() {
        return myPhotoList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PhotoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_cell_photo, parent, false);
        PhotoViewHolder photoViewHolder = new PhotoViewHolder(view);
        return photoViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PhotoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyPhoto myPhoto = myPhotoList.get(position);
        holder.bindPhoto(myPhoto);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (myPhotoList == null){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return myPhotoList.size();
        }
    }

    public class PhotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView thumbnail;
        private TextView title;

        public PhotoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_cell_photo_thumbnail);
            this.title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_cell_photo_title);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectedPhotoListener.selectePhoto(getAdapterPosition(), myPhotoList);
                }
            });
        }

        public void bindPhoto(MyPhoto myPhoto) {
            Glide.with(itemView).load(myPhoto.getThumbnailUrl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(thumbnail);
            title.setText(myPhoto.getTitle());
        }
    }

    public interface SelectedPhotoListener {
        public void selectePhoto(Integer position, List<MyPhoto> myPhotoList);
    }
}
```

Object dao

```
public class MyPhotoDao extends MyRetrofit {
    private JsonPlaceholderService service;


    public MyPhotoDao() {
        super("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/");
        service = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceholderService.class);
    }

    public void getPhotos(String fixedUrl, final ResultListener<MyPhotoContainer> listenerOfTheController) {
        Call<MyPhotoContainer> call = service.jsonPlaceholderPhoto(fixedUrl);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MyPhotoContainer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MyPhotoContainer> call, Response<MyPhotoContainer> response) {

                MyPhotoContainer myPhotoContainer = response.body();
                listenerOfTheController.finish(myPhotoContainer);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MyPhotoContainer> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void getAlbum(String fixedUrl, final ResultListener<List<Album>> listenerOfTheController){
        Call<List<Album>> call = service.jsonPlaceholderAlbum(fixedUrl);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Album>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Album>> call, Response<List<Album>> response) {
                List<Album> albumList = response.body();
                listenerOfTheController.finish(albumList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Album>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Object controller

```
public class MyPhotoController {

    public void getPhotos(String fixedUrl, final ResultListener<MyPhotoContainer> listenerOfTheView) {
        MyPhotoDao myPhotoDao = new MyPhotoDao();
        myPhotoDao.getPhotos(fixedUrl, new ResultListener<MyPhotoContainer>() {
            @Override
            public void finish(MyPhotoContainer result) {
                listenerOfTheView.finish(result);
            }
        });
    }

    public void getAlbums(String fixedUrl, final ResultListener<List<Album>> listenerOfTheView){
        MyPhotoDao myPhotoDao = new MyPhotoDao();
        myPhotoDao.getAlbum(fixedUrl, new ResultListener<List<Album>>() {
            @Override
            public void finish(List<Album> result) {
                listenerOfTheView.finish(result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Retrofit object

```
public abstract class MyRetrofit {
    protected Retrofit retrofit;

    public MyRetrofit(String baseUrl) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        retrofit = builder.build();
    }
}
```

Object I'm trying to GET

```
public class MyPhoto implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("AlbumId")
    private Integer albumNumber;
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer photoId;
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("url")
    private String photoUrl;
    private String thumbnailUrl;


    public Integer getAlbumNumber() {
        return albumNumber;
    }

    public Integer getPhotoId() {
        return photoId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl() {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }
}
```

Object container

```
public class MyPhotoContainer implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("array")
    private List<MyPhoto> mPhotoList;

    public List<MyPhoto> getmPhotoList() {
        return mPhotoList;
    }
}
```

If there is anything missing please let me know.
Any help and comments are apreciated!

Comment: You do not need to use `MyPhotoContainer`. Response `JSON` is a `JSON Array` with `JSON Object`s. `getPhotos` method should look like similar to `getAlbum` method: `public void getPhotos(String fixedUrl, final ResultListener<List<MyPhoto>> listenerOfTheView)`

Comment: the call to get albums is not working either so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: For sure, `JSON` behind the URL does not fit to `POJO` classes. There is no `array` property there.

Comment: so instead of the attribute `List` I should replace it with an `array`? @MichałZiober

Comment: Use `getAlbum()` method instead of `getPhotos()` in your code. Because the API returns an array of photos (List).

Comment: @MichałZiober well..your answer worked so add it as a response so I can mark it as correct. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON` payload does not fit to `POJO` classes. You do not need to use `MyPhotoContainer` class at all. Response `JSON` is a `JSON Array` with directly placed `JSON Object`s. `getPhotos` method should look similar to `getAlbum` method. Try:

```
public void getPhotos(String fixedUrl, final ResultListener<List<MyPhoto>> listenerOfTheView)
```